# PHP-How to check if the textbox contains one word or two?

Tags: php, if-statement, cpu-word

Now I want to check if this text box contains one word or two, for example

```
 if ($_POST['mytext'] == two words){
 echo "That is Perfect";
} else{
echo "We don't accept this";
}
```

and I tried

```
 if ($_POST['mytext'] > 1){
 echo "That is Perfect";
} else{
echo "We don't accept this";
}
```

and it didn't work

that what I mean so how to make it?
Hope to find a way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explode the contents on space, and count the number of elements in the resulting array?

Comment: How can the words be separated? If it's just spaces, use `explode` otherwise you'd have to look at `preg_split`.

Comment: Somehow I don't want to think of what process brought you to assume that `> 1` in php would count words in a string, instead of the more normal "bigger than 1" comparison...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define *two words* as *"some characters followed by one space followed by some characters"* then you can do something like:

```
$mytext = $_POST["mytext"];
$parts = explode(" ", $mytext);
if (count($parts) !== 2) {
    throw new Exception("too many or too little!");
}
if (strlen($parts[0]) === 0 || strlen($parts[1]) === 0) {
    throw new Exception("not enough characters!");
}
```

Keep in mind that this allows a string like `"@ !"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_word_count()`:

```
if (str_word_count($_POST['mytext']) > 1){
  echo "That is Perfect";
} else{
  echo "We don't accept this"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the

```
`substr_count('some text', ' ');
```

it will return the number of space,.

Comment: How does that help? What about `"    A      "`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $text= preg_split(" ",$_POST['mytext']);

   if (count($text) > 1){
     echo "That is Perfect";
    } else{
       echo "We don't accept this";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that was a great help from you :D